TypeError in the dfareporting_utils file. Python Samples for Google DFA reporting
I am new to Google Ads API, and I am following the following repository, which contains python samples for the dfa reporting API:
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-dfa-reporting-samples/blob/main/python/v4/
I am using an user account, and I am able to run authenticate_user_account.py obtaining authentification successful. However, when I am trying to run the get_campaigns.py I obtain a TypeError:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jozaita/Documents/googleads-dfa-reporting-samples/python/v4/get_campaigns.py", line 64, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/jozaita/Documents/googleads-dfa-reporting-samples/python/v4/get_campaigns.py", line 43, in main
    request = service.campaigns().list(profileId=profile_id)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/jozaita/Documents/googleads-dfa-reporting-samples/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 1122, in method
    for pvalue in pvalues:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable


I am running the command as :
python3 python/v4/get_campaigns.py  XXXXXXXXX

Where XXXXXXXXX is a number.
Can anyone help to show which is my mistake, or how can I get over this issue?
Thank you very much in advance
I searched in google there is additional information , I have found the same mistake in the Google Ad GoogleGroups but I am not able to join or get to the GoogleGroups conversation
